# Find all the entire functions such that $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{2\pi}_0|f(re^{i\theta})|d\theta \leqslant 5r^\frac{2}{7}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all the entire functions such that $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{2\pi}_0|f(re^{i\theta})|d\theta \leqslant 5r^\frac{2}{7}$.

My first thought is to use Liouville's theorem, but I do not know where to start. Then I consider the Mean value theorem which says that $f(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{2\pi}_0f(re^{i\theta})d\theta$, so basically I have $|f(0)| \leqslant 5r^{\frac{2}{7}}$ for arbitrary $r$. I conclude that $f(0) = 0$. What is next?

Comment: Do you know about Cauchy's integral formula? For derivatives?

Comment: I do not know that, does this problem require that formula?

Comment: There are other ways. What the most suitable or most elegant way accessible is, depends on what instruments one can use. What sort of stuff have you learned so far?

Comment: Do you have any reference on that formula? I have learned about most versions of CIF and CIT, but I do not really think we ever covered a formula for its derivative. But on second thought it might not be very hard to derive one, since I can write out the taylor expansion using the CIF.

Comment: I just mean $$f^{(k)}(z) = \frac{k!}{2\pi i} \int_{\lvert \zeta - z_0\rvert = r} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^{k+1}}\,d\zeta$$ for $\lvert z-z_0\rvert < r$. That's very standard.

Comment: Yes, I do know this.

Comment: Good. Use it to obtain a bound for $\lvert f^{(k)}(0)\rvert$.

Comment: Oh, I see your point. All terms rather than the constant term will vanish right?

Comment: The constant term vanishes too. One just lets $r\to 0$ for that rather than $r\to +\infty$ as for $k > 0$.

Comment: So in this case only zero function is valid right?